# what is instanceHandle in hotspot jvm source code?

Tags: c++, jvm, jvm-hotspot

In the JVM hotspot source code, in [file "compileBroker.cpp" line 695](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/hotspot/file/fe14c1d82da5/src/share/vm/compiler/compileBroker.cpp), it has a "instanceHandle", but I can't find its definition.

Is there any Hotspot code guru who might know where its definition is?

Comment: What's the context? What are you actually trying to find out here?

Comment: `instanceHandle` is a data type, but I don't know what it's definition is. The original purpose for me learning the JVM compilation process is something else. I am correct that instanceHandle is a data type right? Also, what "context" is needed?